# Modules over dedekind domain

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modules

Let $L$ be a finitely generated module over a dedekind ring $R$ and let $M$ be a submodule of $L$ such that $L/M$ is finite. I want to describe $L/M$. For a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$, let denote by $M_\mathfrak{p}$ the submodule of all those $x\in L$ for which there exists $s\in R\setminus \mathfrak{p}$ such that $sx\in M$. Is it true that $L/M\cong \prod_\mathfrak{p} L/M_\mathfrak{p}$?. I have problems to prove surjectivity of $L\rightarrow \prod_\mathfrak{p} L/M_\mathfrak{p}$. Thanks!

Comment: $L/M$ finite as in "finitely many elements"? The use of "finite" in commutative algebra sometimes tricks me...

Comment: Yes, it is finite as set.